# HE Top Loading Clothes Washer - water drainage

Tags: washing-machine

My GE HE clothes washer ALWAYS has water under the tub - when you move the tub you hear it sloshing around.

Is this normal?

If not, thoughts on getting a proper draining?

Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My Sears Kenmore top loader washer machine tub has a construction where there is a donut shaped compartment built around the bottom of the tub. It has water inside of it!!

A couple of years ago when I replaced the tub bearings I was mildly surprised to note this interesting construction. It did not leak or pour out when I had removed the tub during the repair. I can only guess that the water plays a role in the dynamics of the tub motion in conjunction with baffles inside the water compartment.

So I would guess that this is normal for your GE washer tub as well.